# Why is the shortcut's target sometimes read-only in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, links

I observe, that sometimes in the sortcut's options the target is setable (s. the first screenshot) and sometimes it's read-only (s. the second one).

Why? What does it depend on? Is there a way to change it for a special shortcut an / or globally?

[image: WSL-shortcut-with-setable-target]

[image: WSL-shortcut-with-readonly-target]

Comment: Try also working through this Microsoft Answers solution.    https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/shortcut-properties-greyed-out/a379c1a1-a67b-4af1-8a8a-a99ef374b8c5